# Why is GetVirtualPath failing after upgrading to .NET 4

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I have the following route defined:

```
 var route = new Route("{id}/{a}/{b}", new MvcRouteHandler());
 route.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Show" });
 route.Defaults.Add("a", "");
 route.Defaults.Add("b", "");
```

And the following controller code:

```
public ActionResult Show(int id)
{
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    routeValues["Controller"] = "Home";
    routeValues["Action"] = "Show";
    routeValues["id"] = 1;
    var requestContext = new RequestContext(this.HttpContext, RouteData);
    var rv = route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeValues);
    // when targetting .NET 4 rv is null, when its 3.5 it is "/1"

 }
```

Why does this code return a route in .NET 3.5 and not in .NET 4.0?

Comment: have any of the methods you are calling been upgraded to contain the new optional parameters in .net 4? I have seen this cause problems as it changes the way the binding works.

Comment: Yerp something changed with the binding process.  I notice this works when I only have one optional param. I am not using the new .net 4 optional params

Comment: This appears to be a slight breaking change. I'm looking into it and will follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing `a` and `b` with `Controller` and `Action` in your route? Since `Controller` and `Action` are required by the routing engine, I suggest you stick with them. The following example works:

```
var route = new Route("{Id}/{Controller}/{Action}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary
  {
    { "Id", "" },
    { "Controller", "Home" },
    { "Action", "Show" },
  }
};

ActionResult Show(int id)
{
  RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
  routeValues["Controller"] = "Home";
  routeValues["Action"] = "Show";
  routeValues["Id"] = 1;
  var requestContext = new RequestContext(this.HttpContext, RouteData);
  var rv = route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeValues);
  // rv.VirtualPath == "1".
}
```